# Why doesn't reversed() accept a generator?

Tags: python, list, generator, reverse

I am struggling with writing things like this:

```
list(reversed(list(el.iterancestors()))) + [1,2,3]
```

Where generators suck, because I am forced to consume the them into lists.

Is there a way to simplify this? I think `reversed()` should accept an iterator, am I wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generators are not guaranteed to have a last item, so can't be reversed. What would be the output of the following?

```
from itertools import cycle

reversed(cycle('abc'))
```

There is also the risk of accidentally eating all your memory:

```
from itertools import permutations
reversed(permutations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 10)) # 19,275,223,968,000 tuples
```

Note that the point of `reversed()` is to be *memory efficient*. For sequences, so objects with an index (lists, strings, tuples, ranges), `reversed()` produces an iterator that uses an internal index, which starts at `len(inputobject) - 1`, and progresses down to `0` as you iterate. It never has to create a copy of the input sequence that way, but that trick can only work on something that already has a length and supports random access.

For *your case* I'd not use `reversed()` *anyway*. You want a list as output, not a generator, so use slicing to reverse the list instead:

```
list(el.iterancestors())[::-1] + [1, 2, 3]
```

Memory efficiency is not an issue here, as you are building a new list object.